# C# / EmguCV - Convert an uploaded HttpPostedFileBase to a Emgu.CV.Mat

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have an `MVC` application where one of my controllers receives an uploaded file (image) as an `HttpPostedFileBase` object.

I am trying to process the image using `EmguCV`, but I'm having difficulty converting my `HttpPostedFileBase` to the `EmguCV` matrix object `Emgu.CV.Mat` (which is just a `C#` implementation of a `cv::Mat` object).

There is a constructor for `Mat` that looks like:

```
public Mat(int rows, int cols, DepthType type, int channels, IntPtr data, int step);
```

but I'm not sure how to get the `type`, `data`, and `step` from my starting `HttpPostedFileBase` object. Is this possible?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171696/how-do-you-convert-a-httppostedfilebase-to-an-image), that I can convert an `HttpPostedFileBase` to an `Image` object (I think that's in the `System.Drawing` namespace), which allows me to see the height and width. **But how can I use this information to get the rest of the required parameters to send the the `Mat()` constructor?**

Comment: Did you made it? Or are you still trying? Do you need more help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the **Emgu** specification those parameters mean:

```
  /// <param name="type">Mat element type

  /// <param name="channels">Number of channels

  /// <param name="data">
  /// Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step parameters do not  
  /// allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize the matrix header that points to the 
  /// specified data, which means that no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and 
  /// can be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. The external data is not 
  /// automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

  /// <param name="step">
  /// Number of bytes each matrix row occupies. 
  /// The value should include the padding bytes at the end of each row, if any.
```

- `type` is of the type `CvEnum.DepthType`, which is the depth of the image, you can pass `CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F` which stands for 32bit depth images, other possible values are of the form `CvEnum.DepthType.Cv{x}{t}`, where {x} is any value of the set {8,16,32,64} and {t} can be `S`for `Single` or `F` for `Float`.
- `channels`, depend on the type of image but I think you can use `4`from ARGB.

For the other 2 parameters, if you  don't need the optimization part, you can just use this constructor of the `Mat` class:

```
public Mat(int rows, int cols, DepthType type, int channels)
```

If you really want to use the optimized version, then (continuing):

- `data`, you can pass the Bitmap.GetHbitmap() which returns an IntPtr to the user data.
- `step`, for this guy, I'll give you an informed guess, if for each pixel you have 4 channels, and each channel ranges from 0 to 255 (8bits), `8*4 = 32`, so for every width of unit you need 32 bits. Assuming this is correct, each row haves `32*width` bits, converting it to bytes `((8*4)*width)/8 = 4*width`, which is the number of channels, multiplied by the image width.

**UPDATE**

Other way to get the `data` and `step` is from [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx) class, like this (excerpt from the MSDN resource):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream, true, true));

// Lock the bitmap's bits.  
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmp.PixelFormat);

// data = scan0 is a pointer to our memory block.
IntPtr data = bmpData.Scan0;

// step = stride = amount of bytes for a single line of the image
int step = bmpData.Stride;

// So you can try to get you Mat instance like this:
Mat mat = new Mat(bmp.Height, bmp.Width, CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 4, data, step);

// Unlock the bits.
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Have not tested this solution, but you can give it a try.
My answer was based on the **Emgu** code [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV/Mat.cs#l81)., **Bitmap IntPtr** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and also on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917270/how-do-i-get-a-net-bitmap-and-an-opencv-image-to-point-to-the-same-chunk-of-mem) which help me also acquiring further understanding on this.

**I have seen other ways to do it also, and unless you really need to call that complete constructor, I would try this approach, seems cleaner:**

```
HttpPostedFileBase file //your file must be available is this context.

if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    // your so wanted Mat!
    Mat img = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
}
```

**NOTE**

There are great tutorials in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/core/table_of_content_core/table_of_content_core.html). Just have a look at the available tutorials for the core module. In particular, this [one](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html).

Comment: Hi, how can I create a Mat from an Image<Bgra, Byte> ? Trying many ways with EmguCV but each fails

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way to do what you want is to create a `Bitmap` from the Image you get following your link on how to convert an `HttpPostedFileBase` to `Bitmap`. The `Bitmap` class has a constructor with an `Image` parameter. You can then create an `Emgu.CV.Image` using this `Bitmap`, again the `Image` class can take a `Bitmap` in the constructor. The drawback of these method is that you will get an `Image` and not a `Mat`.

Now, you asked how to create a `Mat` object and I'm not sure what you're talking about because I couldn't find this class in EmguCV (2.4.9). There is a `Matrix` class but its constructor doesn't look like the one in your question. So to give you more information about the `type`, `data` and `step` parameters, know that the `type` is dependent on the `PixelFormat` property of the Image. It is an enum which can have about 20 different values. In my test the image had a `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` value, which means it is a 3-channels images where each channel is 8-bits, so the type should be byte in this case. I would suggest to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835588/get-pixel-length-from-pixelformat) link on how to get the bit-depth for a specified PixelFormat.

For the data parameter, you will need to get the `BitmapData` from the `Bitmap` and get the `Scan0` property as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303493/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-image-to-intptr-in-c).

For the step parameter, you will again need the `BitmapData` but this time it is the `Stride` parameter which represents the step.